# Am I loading scripts correctly in sinatra?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, datamapper

I have never done anything in sinatra before and decided to try it out on a project. I am confused on how script loading works. It seems to be intermittently working. Sometimes 2 scripts/css files will have internal server errors, and sometime they will all have errors.

This is my layout.erb :

```
<!doctype html>

<html>

  <head>
    <title>An HTML5 box of sand</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="/assets/stylesheets/style.less">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script><!--loads jquery-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script><!--loads jquery ui-->  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/lib/handlebars.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js/lib/less-1.3.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/script.js"></script><!--This is the place where you play!!!-->

  </head>

<body>
<%= yield  %>
</body>

</html>
```

I have the assets folder inside of the public folder /public/assets. It is weird because sometimes it will load the assets/js/script.js file, and not load the handlebars file. Other times it will load the handlebars and not the script.js file. I am not sure what is going on.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~UPDATE~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Discovered the problem but don't know how to fix it.

So, it seems that because I am using data mapper the auto_migrate! method is somehow screwing with how the assets are being loaded. Is there something I can do about this. Here is what I have in my app.rb file:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'data_mapper'


# Include the models
require './models/User'



# Connect to mysql
DataMapper.setup(:default, "mysql://root@localhost/dev_landing")


#This line is what is messing everything up. 
DataMapper.auto_migrate!



set :public_folder, 'public'




get '/' do 
    erb :home
end
```

I set up data mapper like this because I read in a tutorial that this is how you get it to automatically create the tables you specify in your models. Is there a better way to do this so that it is not messing up the loading of my scritps and css?

Comment: Just a tiny pointer, it's beneficial to keep all script tags attributes defined in the same order (the less script reference has different ordering) as it'll gzip better on production. (Albiet, you'd likely have better savings by combining and minifying the scripts :)

Answer (score 0):

`DataMapper.auto_migrate!` deletes existing tables in case they exist and creates them again.

So calling this function means: you lose all your data.  (That's why there is an exclamation mark at the end, meaning: watch out!)  In case your schema is still under heavy development, I suggest you to replace `DataMapper.auto_migrate!` by `DataMapper.auto_upgrade!`.  It does not wipe your old data, instead it tries to modify the underlying tables while trying to keep the data.  The exclamation mark is still there because your data might still get slightly damaged because changing the schema without corrupting the data is not always possible.

Another thing, the order of calls must be changed.  Currently it is:

1. Model definitions
2. `DataMapper.Setup`
3. `DataMapper.auto_migrate!`
4. Your route definitions etc.

But it should be instead:

1. `DataMapper.Setup`
2. Model definitions
3. <strike>DataMapper.auto_migrate!</strike> `DataMapper.auto_upgrade!`
4. `DataMapper.finalize` (you forgot that one)
5. Your route definitions etc.

When something is screwed up with datamapper, the error messages can be weird/misleading.  By the way, make sure that there are *no* calls to the database from inside your views.  These calls belong into the controller, without any exception in my opinion.  This way your app naturally follows the MVC pattern.  (After all Sinatra hardly enforces any other structure... ;))